# How do I SELECT only rows from table b that have all the same values for a given column per foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that just has ID's.
Another table that has ID plus a couple other columns.
One such column is [set], for reference.

I am trying to build a join query on only the ID's in table2 that have the same value for every row in column [set], not just ID'S that have a duplicate value in [set] plus another different value. So, each ID in table2 can have multiple rows.

table1

| [id] |
| --- |
| a1 |
| a2 |

table2

| [id] | [op] | [set] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 22 | cut |
| a1 | 21 | cut |
| a2 | 23 | cut |
| a2 | 25 | cut |
| a2 | 24 | slice |

In the given example, 'a2' would not fit the criteria because the values in column [set] are not all the same.

My query isn't working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.ID)
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, B.SET
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(B.SET)) =1
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT A.ID` and `COUNT(DISTINCT B.SET)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're grouping by `id` and `set`, so by definition within each group, there will be just one value for `set`. Remove it from the `group by` clause and you should be OK. Also, not that since you're grouping by the `id`, you don't need a `distinct` on it:

```sql
SELECT   A.ID -- Distinct removed. It's not wrong, just redundant
FROM     TABLE1 A
INNER    JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID -- Grouping by b.set removed
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT(B.SET)) = 1
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT(B.SET))` may be confusing since `DISTINCT` looks like a function. I think it should be easier to read as `COUNT(DISTINCT B.SET)`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Personally, I agree, but i was trying to keep OP's query with as little changes as possible.